# Displaying subtitles using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, subtitle

I'm currently using [jquery.srt.js](http://v2v.cc/~j/jquery.srt/) to display subtitles for some videos that I have.

What I am trying to accomplish is displaying the whole text file of the subtitles in a webpage.

This is what I have in my html document.  How can I get the 'data-srt' (a local file) contents?
Thanks

```
<div id='srt'
     class="srt"
     data-video="video"
     data-srt="sample.srt" />

</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
    $(function()
    {
        $.get($("#srt").data("srt"), function(text) {
            alert(text);
        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried the above editied version but instead of displaying the subtitle text it gives me:
**[object XMLDocument]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using W3C DOM methods, but your file indicates you're using jQuery. So, the following is shorter using jQuery:

```
$.get($("#srt").data("srt"), function(text){
  alert(text); // Show the subtitles from the text file.
});
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried the above and edited my question.  How would I access the object XMLDocument to extract the whole .srt text?

Comment: The code above worked.  I had to setup an apache server to get the results.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming sample.srt is a text file located on the webserver?  You can try performing an ajax call to the text file and using javascript to display the response text to an html element.  Use jQuery to perform that AJAX call:

```
$.ajax(
{
   url: $("#srt").attr("data-srt"),
   success: function(responseText)
   {
       alert(responseText);
   }
});
```

Comment: The text file is actually local.  I'm just experimenting with a webpage and how I want it to display text.

Comment: But if you choose this method, then the .srt file will be on the webserver, right?  What I meant is that you won't try to access a local file that the user has.  Both this suggestion and the much more concise version offered by say2joe should work.  It is interesting that you are getting an object reference and not the actual text.  Does the file exist?  Is it located in the same directory as the html file with this code?

Comment: You are right.  In the future I will not be accessing local files.  The file does exist and its right next to the .html file in the same directory.  If you follow the link above 'jquery.srt.js' I am using the video and srt file as an example.  You can see for yourself.  Thanks

Comment: Pretty nifty plugin.  I am still unsure why you would be getting an object reference instead of the actual text.  I tried it with various file formats and am still getting the text as it is written on the file.  Which browser are you using?  Have you tried running this in other browsers?

Comment: I'm using firefox 14 and chrome 20.0.1132.57.  Chrome won't allow access to local files so it won't work.  I'll setup an apache server and see if it'll work from there

Comment: I got the apache server up and running.  Copy/paste the needed files.  Work fine now.  That did the trick.  Although I didn't use your code I didn't mark it as correct.  But I would upvote you if I could.  Thanks again!